# want to show dynamic value in this jsp page

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee, servlets

Here is my jsp psge:

```
<%  while(rs.next()){ %>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="chkName" onclick="selectall()"></td> 
<td><input type="text"  name="empId" value="<%= rs.getString(1)%> "   

disabled="disabled"  maxlength="10"></td>
<td><input type="text" name="device" value="<%= rs.getString(2)%>"  

disabled="disabled" maxlength="10"></td>
<td><input type="text"  name="features" value="<%= rs.getString(3)%>"   

disabled="disabled" maxlength="60"></td>
<td><input type="text"  name="policyName" value="<%= rs.getString(4)%>" 

disabled="disabled" maxlength="10"></td>
<td><input type="text" name="password" id="password" 

disabled="disabled" value="<%=  rs.getString(5) %>" ><input 

type="button" name="Password" id="Password" value="Reset  Password" 

onclick="fillFields(this);"></td>
</tr>
<% } 
%>
</table>
<td><input type="submit" value="Save" colspan="2" onclick= "save

(this)"></td>
<td><input type="submit" value="Delete" colspan="2" onclick="deleted

(this)"></td>
</center>
</form>
<%
```

Actually this jsp showing a joining table(user_table & policy_management) where I want to update this joined table simultaneously.And I want to put it in a session sothat I can set and get it's attribute inthe next servlet page.

So can you help me,exactly what I have to do for this...

Comment: Where is form start tag ? And see this http://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info

Answer (score 1):

remove `disabled=disabled` ,then you can get this forms value in servlet